# Jquery ajax facebox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a "live search" type of page, which calls another page with ajax to check the validity of an input. It returns an image that you can click on to see more information about the product. The image has a rel="facebox" attribute, that is meant to bring up a facebox with div information in it when clicked. However, I must click on the image twice for the facebox to load. Here is the Jquery live code I'm using:

```
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            $('a[rel*=facebox]').live("click", function() {
                $(this).facebox();
            });
        });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well it's either the click event messing up or the actual facebox function not doing what you want. Try putting an alert there so you know for sure whether the event is firing. Also, you don't need to wait for `document.ready` for live()

Comment: I removed the document.ready part and added an alert, but nothing happened upon click. I also have another link that is part of the main page that will fire the first-time if an ajax call has been made. Otherwise it must be clicked twice as well (hope I explained that alright)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening, is that you're **initializing** facebox `onclick`. The first call will add a handle to the `click event` to open the facebox, so if you don't have a callback to do this when you receive those live results, you'll have to do something like this:

```
$('a[rel*=facebox]').live("click", function() {
    $(this).unbind("click").facebox().trigger("click");
    return false;
}
```

But this is *ugly* :-(. Even, it's possible that, as you're using "live", the event will be re-binded to the element when some new element arrives :S You can verify this with `console.log`.

A cleaner way, is add an init property to facebox, called autoStart or something similar, wich will initialize the facebox, and open it in the same function.

Good luck!

Comment: `.unbind("click").facebox().trigger("click");` Why would you try to trigger something you just explicitly removed?

Comment: Because you're calling to the event binded by facebox. And you unbind it because you don't want to initialize this element again.

Comment: Ah. Didn't realize FaceBox was a plugin. Silly me. EDIT: +1!

Comment: This worked to get the facebox open on the first click, but also adds #divname to the url. Any idea why that is happening?

Comment: Sure! i've forgot to add a return false; at the end of the function. Sorry! I'll edit it now.

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks a lot, I'll use this method for the moment and look at making it cleaner later :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this only:

```
$(function(){
    $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox();
});
```

or even drop the * (if that's the only class on a link)
it will create the facebox div structure, when you're using it with click event first click is generating the div and second one is opening the facebox.

Oh one more thing, as the content is dynamically generated, you can use callback to run this line of code to reattach the click event.

Cheers

G.

Comment: I understand that you're using it with <a href="#divname" rel="facebox">link</a> to show a hidden div content? If after click you're getting #divname in the url then possibly it's not preventing the default click i.e. return false or event.preventDefault(); isn't kicking in, could you post the code you're using, it's hard to debug it without seing all bits of script

Comment: Yes, thats exactly how I was using it. I ended up using the method above, but thanks a lot for your help (and a working script) anyway!